# Click to expand shall result in collapsing other opened items?

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

when i click on the menu item, i want just that item to expand and rest shall collapse.

example: i click on item 1 to expand it, then i click on item 2. So, in this case item 1 shall collapse itself.

**html**

```
<ul class="footernav">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="topToggle">Item 1</a>
    <div class="typeToggle typeCont">
    Link area one
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="topToggle">Item 2</a>
    <div class="typeToggle filterCont">Link area two</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".topToggle").click( function () {  
   $(this).parent().children('.typeToggle').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EpXR6/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `slideUp()` all `.typeToggles` before you `slideToggle()` the specific one.

```
$(".topToggle").click(function () {
        $(".typeToggle").slideUp();
        $(this).parent().children('.typeToggle').slideToggle();
    });
```

This will result in a UP/DOWN motion if you click the already expanded item but you could put in some checks to stop that if you wish.

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpXR6/2/)**

---

Edit:

This is what is known as an Accordion and many examples and plugins can be found on the web. jQuery UI provides this functionality you can see it [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/); if you don't want to recreate the functionality it is *usually* trivial to add a plugin and have it perform this for you.