# Drop down only one menu at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

So far I have this [**drop-down menu**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mareksmakosz/8aKgY/7/). When I click on either "Menu", "Menu1" or "Menu2", the links under it will drop down.

The problem: 
I need to display only one drop-down at a time, so that the user can switch between them.

I tried to apply `css('overflow', 'hidden');` to the menu currently dropped down, but it won't work, since the `overflow: visible !important;` is applied to the `.clicked` class.
Please help, anything will be highly appreciated!

Comment: you can achieve this using jquery. Here is a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270323/click-to-expand-shall-result-in-collapsing-other-opened-items

Comment: I couldn't help in time... your html is really hard to read. Do you really need so much ul/li ? o_O'

Comment: @Apolo you still have your chance :) The menu should close on the second click, so I'm afraid I need to stick to toggleClass. And yes, the markup must remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try when you click on a element remove `class clicked` from all elements and add `class clicked` to the element that is clicked

```
$("#product-menu>ul>li").click(function () {
    var hidden = $(this).find('.clicked');
    $("#product-menu>ul>li").removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $('.productSubmenu').width(menuWidth);
});
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8aKgY/9/)

**UPDATE**

If you want also on second click menu to be closed try checking if clicked item has already `class clicked`:

```
$("#product-menu>ul>li").click(function () {
    var hidden = $(this).find('.clicked');
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked')
    } else {
        $("#product-menu>ul>li").removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');

    }
    $('.productSubmenu').width(menuWidth);
});
```

[DEMO2](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8aKgY/20/)

Comment: It fixes it partially, but I need the menu to also close on the second click.

Comment: Solved, will mark it as answered when I can. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to close the links

```
$("#product-menu>ul>li").click(function () {
    var hidden = $(this).find('.clicked');
    $("#product-menu>ul>li").removeClass('clicked');
    $("#product-menu .productSubmenu2").hide(); // this one I added
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $('.productSubmenu').width(menuWidth);
});
```